# Bot Framework - Task Module won't start/pop up

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I'm trying to open a task module in my chat bot. The bot is already connected to Teams Channel (but no App installed). The bot is working totally fine until the task module should pop up, because it doesn't. Nothing happens at all, although my code is (in my eyes) the same as the sample code microsoft provides for task modules.

On MessageActivityAsync I create a hero card with 3 buttons.

```
var card = new HeroCard
{
  Text = "You can upload an image or select one of the following choices",
  Buttons = new[] { new UISettings(400, 200, "TITLE1", "exercise1", "TITLE1"),
                    new UISettings(400, 200, "TITLE2", "exercise2", "TITLE2"),
                    new UISettings(400, 200, "TITLE3", "exercise3", "TITLE3")}
  .Select(cardType => new TaskModuleAction(cardType.ButtonTitle, new CardTaskFetchValue<string>() { Data = cardType.Id })).ToList<CardAction>(),
};
```

with CardTaskFetchValue and UISettings classes defined as the following

```
public class CardTaskFetchValue<T>
{
  [JsonProperty("type")]
  public object Type { get; set; } = "task/fetch";

  [JsonProperty("data")]
  public T Data { get; set; }
}

public class UISettings
{
    public UISettings(int width, int height, string title, string id, string buttonTitle)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
        Title = title;
        Id = id;
        ButtonTitle = buttonTitle;
    }

    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ButtonTitle { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

The user can chose between one of the three buttons to start the corresponding task module. But somehow nothing happens, allthough I override the OnTeamsTaskModuleFetchAsync function.

```
protected override Task<TaskModuleResponse> OnTeamsTaskModuleFetchAsync(ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext, TaskModuleRequest taskModuleRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  var asJobject = JObject.FromObject(taskModuleRequest.Data);
  var value = asJobject.ToObject<CardTaskFetchValue<string>>()?.Data;
    
  var taskInfo = new TaskModuleTaskInfo();                
  taskInfo.Card = CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment(Path.Combine(".", "Resources", "AdaptiveCardExample.json"));
  SetTaskInfo(taskInfo, new UISettings(400, 200, "Adaptive Card: Inputs", "AdaptiveCard", "Adaptive Card"));
    
  return Task.FromResult(taskInfo.ToTaskModuleResponse());
}
```

My testing code is similar the official smaple code for task modules (https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/54.teams-task-module/Bots/TeamsTaskModuleBot.cs) but won't work. Any recommendations/help/advises for me?

Comment: As mentioned in the sample READMEs, you must add your AppId to the manifest and upload it as a custom app to your Teams client before the Task Module will work. Enabling the Teams channel simply allows your bot to communicate with Teams. You still need to install the app before it will work fully. Step 6 in the README of the sample you linked shows how to do it.

Note that this does not require the bot to be running in Azure.